# This should be a simple CSS styling challenge

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome-devtools, elementor

I want to make the two text items inside the tabs to be centred vertically but I'm struggling. If I alter the line height they look better but not when I shrink the window (not responsive). The webpage in question: https://uk.outdore.co.uk/help/

If you can also add some spacing between the tabs (red arrow) without causing the tabs to go onto 2 rows that would be a bonus.

I can't replicate the issue in a sample of code here - other styles are overriding my efforts within the website, it's far to complex of an environment to produce a minimal reproducible example.

[image]

Comment: Please include a [mcve] directly in the question and not as link to an external site.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I can't replicate the issue in a sample of code here - other styles are overriding my efforts within the website, it's far to complex of an environment to produce a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Although it's an effort, the act of making a basic reproduction often reveals the problem. Using an online IDE like https://codepen.io/trending helps, then it's much easier to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Look into CSS `flexbox` or `grid`, it will alleviate a few things.**

You're using the classic `float` quite a bit however if instead you simply use more modern `flexbox` you can get positioning, wrapping and centering all with a few simple rules and without a media query. Or alternatively you can use `grid` which can deliver this too, with more control over spacing between the items, but no auto-wrapping power so you'd need a media query.

**Firstly**, in the `ul` wrapper, get rid of `float` and use `display:flex`:

```
#epkb-main-page-container.epkb-tabs-template #epkb-content-container ul {
    display: flex; /* By default items will be horizontally oriented */
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* This will automatically stack your items vertically when then items run out of width. If you're picky, you can control this in media queries too. */

    --myGapVariable: 2rem; /* set a gap value we can re-use in other places */
    gap: var(--myGapVariable); /* adds a gap between your items, whether you use flex or grid */
}
```

**Secondly**, in the `li` class, get rid of `float` and `display:block`; use `flex` and it's centering rules:

```
#epkb-main-page-container.epkb-tabs-template .epkb-nav-tabs li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

As well, I don't know why you have this, but either eliminate it or make this `display: flex` (and `!important` should have a space in front of it):

```
#epkb-main-page-container.epkb-tabs-template .active {
    /*display: block !important; */
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Additionally, we set width to 50% but less half of your gap value. Note: This trick is unnecessary if using `grid` (instead of `flex`) method on the `ul`:

```
#epkb-main-page-container.epkb-tabs-template .col-2 {
    width: calc(50% - (var(--myGapVariable) / 2));
}
```

**Thirdly**, for the tab content, I think at this point disable `padding` and see where you stand; it may be unnecessary. In any case, it's strange to use percentages here and/or have a bunch of 1%'s; were you nudging pixels? You shouldn't have to, assuming higher-level things are proper.

```
#epkb-main-page-container.epkb-tabs-template .epkb-nav-tabs li .epkb-category-level-1 {
    /* Disable padding for now until you've smoothed out higher-level stuff; do you even need it? */
    /* padding: 4% 1% 1% 1%; */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

hey i kind of solved your problem
see the width of both the container is 50px so reduce it to 40 px
and then add margin of 10 px to both the element
and you will get the desired gap between the buttons.[see i changed it to 40 pixels and added 10 px of margin give margin to both the element of 10px and reduce the width of both element from 50 to 40px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igCQW.png)
i also changed the border radius to 29% just so it looks better.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

In order to centre vertically a div's content, I would style its class as follows:

```
.divs-class{
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```